# A loop that does not lend itself to vectorization. Can we make it faster?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Code is Functional**

This is a quick example of the type of loop I am doing.  What I am doing is bringing in values every day, having a point (C) that references some of those values and eventually get to Z which is my state at the end of day.  Then we start at a new day, where C references Z (previous day.)  We also have some interdependent activity (such as B referencing the previous C effectively.)

The question is can this be done faster? Unlike other things I have built, this doesn't lend itself to vectorization easy.  However I was wondering if there are creative ways or something I am missing that could speed this up.  Looping that also appends is very slow.

Thanks again!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
global new_dcty
new_dcty = defaultdict(list)

temp = np.zeros((10000,5))
temp = temp + 1
table = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'])


def big_loop(table, days = 10000):

    Z = 0
    C = 0

    for day in range (1,days):

        A = table['aa'].iloc[(day-1)]
        new_dcty["aa"].append(A)

        B = table['bb'].iloc[(day-1)] - C
        new_dcty['bb'].append(B)

        C = Z + min(A, B)
        new_dcty['cc'].append(C)

        D = table['dd'].iloc[(day-1)]
        new_dcty['dd'].append(D)

        E = table['ee'].iloc[(day-1)]
        new_dcty['ee'].append(E)

        Z = C - D - E
        new_dcty['zz'].append(Z)

    #load dictionary into dataframe
    f = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dcty)
    return f

results = big_loop(table)

print(results)
```

Comment: It would be good, if you share sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: The function uses some global variables which you do not show, and is non-functional. Please post actual, valid code.

Comment: I made a few changes, the code is functional now, thanks!

Comment: I think this kind of question is more appropriate in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/